# Whats your workflow between front-end and back-end in a team?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, workflow

Whats your best practice (within MVC) with how you work with front-end-developers and back-end-developers?

Take this example: The team of 3 (1 front-end and 3 back-end) have 10 modules to develop on a homepage. All modules require HTML, CSS, Images as well as controllers and models.

1. How would you usally set up your workflow?
2. If I as a front-end-developer design a module without a proper controller and model, how do I best work with dummie-variables? Best to not use variables and just put "lorem ipsum" in my views? Or should I create a temp-model with set values to not have to edit the view after the back-end-developers are done?
3. Is it better as a front-end-developer to wait until you have all the modules and controllers you need OR maybe work at the same time on a homepage module?

Thanks for sharing!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For me backend is the domain and the service layer which comes in a separate assembly. Frontend is Controllers, ViewModels and Views. So backend developers start by defining the model objects and service interfaces and provide the frontend developers with this assembly. They could also provide a dummy implementation of the service interface which simply returns hardcoded values. So the frontend developers could now start designing the controllers which would consume the services, map the domain models to their corresponding view models and pass them to the views. Once the backend developers have finished implementing the service interfaces they provide the frontend developers with the new version of the assembly and the frontend developers simply switch their DI framework to point to the new implementation instead of the dummy one.

You could also have some frontend developers working on a reusable framework of HTML helpers, extension methods, ... which will be used all along the project.

Answer (score 1):

My workflow goes as follow:

- Back-end developers creates views using proper XHTML markups, without high styling. They are making only mockup.
- Front-end developers creates CSS classes, styles, etc.
- When Back-end developers have finished their work and Front-end developers have all styles done, then it's time to merge. All styles are applied to mockups, and some corrections are applied.